# How to update the scope value using the custom element click event?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

In my `directive` i am replacing the template according to the `index` values. when user click on the template, I need to assign the clicked `directive` value to the `scope` value.

I can't able to directly call the `scope` here in `replaced` element. how to handle this scenario?

here is my `directive` code :

```
var allAppsGallery = function ($compile) {

    return {

        replace : true,

        scope : {
            index : "=",
            app : '='
        },

        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var getTemplate = function (index, app) {

                switch (index) {

                    case 0  :
                    case 13  :
                    case 14  :
                    case 15  :
                    case 5 :

                        return $('<div />', 
                                    {
                                        class:'bgr box'+index,
                                        html : '<h2>'+app.completion+'%</h2><span>'+app.name+'</span>',
                                        click : function () {
                                            alert("hi"); //click works here
                       //but how to update the scope variable?
                                        }
                                    }
                                );

                        break;


                }

            }


            element.html(getTemplate(scope.index, scope.app));
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            element.replaceWith(element.contents());

            element.click(function(event) { //click event not works.

                scope.activeApp = scope.app; //the new value on click need to update
                scope.$appy();

            });



        }

    }

}
```

Here is a live demo:

[LIVE DEMO FOR TEST](http://plnkr.co/edit/JOp3ffzQQ2HITImoYrAW?p=preview)

Comment: `$scope.activeApp = app;` actually i want to update the `app` here. the scope variable name is `$scope.activeApp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to bind `ng-click` before you compile element:

```
case 5:
    return '<div class="bgr" ng-class="\'box\' + index" ng-click="action()">' +
               '<h2>{{app.completion}}</h2><span>{{app.name}}</span>'
           '</div>';
```

...

```
scope.action = function () {
    scope.activeApp = scope.app;
};
```

[Updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/M9UTmVt6qWW9mBPA5qiR?p=preview)

Comment: updated as like you say, but `ng-click` not working.

Comment: I have updated with live demo. can you please look in to it?

Comment: @user2024080 see updated answer and fixed demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/M9UTmVt6qWW9mBPA5qiR?p=preview